# django 3.2.9: update time stamp on view function call

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am using django 3.2.9 as a back-end for my app. This is an excerpt of my Project model:

```
class Project(TimeStampedModel):
    """
    A collection of projects completed 
    """
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, db_index=True)
    account = models.ForeignKey('accounts.Account', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
 
    # I need to add a time stamp here
    copied_on
```

I need to add a time stamp to my Project model that gets updated every time the following view is called:

```
@action(detail=True, methods=['post'])
def copy_to_account(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    user = request.user
    project = self.get_object()
```

So, how can I do it?

Comment: Have you created time stamp previously?

Comment: Only ones that get automatically updated
created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
no idea how to create timestamps that update every time a function is called

Answer (score 0):

After a little search, I came up with the following solution. I'm posting it here in the hopes that it will be useful to someone:

```
class Project(TimeStampedModel):
    """
    A collection of projects completed 
    """
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, db_index=True)
    account = models.ForeignKey('accounts.Account', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    copied_on = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

and added two lines at the end of my View function:

```
@action(detail=True, methods=['post'])
def copy_to_account(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    user = request.user
    project = self.get_object()
    ...
    project.copied_on = timezone.now()
    project.save()
```